# clock picker popover issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

We have a problem in Clock Picker Popover when we add this on Bootstrap pop modal dialog so clock move with the scroll up and down.

if your are not clear:-
please follow the link:- [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/pLh5G/)

please see in the image:-
[image]

js code:-

```
 var input = $('#time');
    input.clockpicker({
    autoclose: true
    });
```

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary**_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to solve this problem with CSS only, but I did not succeed.

So I solved it with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#appointment-modal").scroll(function() {
    var topPos = $("input[id$='time']").offset().top;
    var leftPos = $("input[id$='time']").offset().left;
    console.log(topPos);
    console.log(leftPos);
    $(".popover").css("top", topPos + 35);
    $(".popover").css("left", leftPos);
  });
});
```

Take a look in this fiddle: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathiasfcx/pLh5G/76/)